The right model for this dependent variable distribution
My academic research is on the impact of some business- and location-related factors on businesses' overall rating on GoogleMaps. Overall rating is calculated as the average of a business' 1-5 star ratings so it has a range of 1-5 but doesn't have to be integer. The goal here is to explain and predict overall ratings.
Business-related factors are like businesses' age and number of services. Location-related factors are like population density. Since businesses are nested in locations, I'm thinking of mixed effects models.
My specific question is about the peculiar distribution of my dependent variable as you can see in the histogram and value counts below. First, about 95% of values are in the 3.5 -5 range. Second, it can not range below or above 1-5.  I looked into probit/logit but they seem to be appropriate only for discrete variables. I don't think overall rating is discrete (it has 33 unique levels in my dataset). I also think a simple linear model is not appropriate since it won't limit the predictions to 1-5.
Given the situation,

what is your suggested choice of model that I should use?
Relatedly, do you think I should categorize or transform in any other way the dependent variable?




Depending on how granular your variable is (you wrote "doesn't have to be integer", but does that imply only something like 3.5, or also 3.146?), my first thought would be an ordered logit.

What is the goal of your analysis? Describe associational patterns in the data, predict future ratings, something else?

See @MichaelM 's answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74372/linear-regression-with-strongly-non-normal-response-variable.

@dimitriy The goal is typical regression's: explain and predict the expected values of dependent variable given values of the independent variables. This is academic research.

@Durden Thank you. Please see the value counts output added to my post. There are only 33 unique levels in the variable. Given that you recommended logit, are you comfortable considering this variable as categorical? I may be wrong but it feels continuous to me (no continuous variable is in fact uncountable in practice despite the textbook definition)

@dimitriy, do you deem the variable to be discrete or continuous given the output of the value counts in the post?

In short, the link I posted says that the distribution of the response variable is irrelevant if the objective is to perform a regression.  It is the distribution of the residuals that would be more relevant to assessing the fit of a model.

@JimB, I understand that. But do we not choose our models based on the nature and measurement of the dependent variable, for example Poisson for counts or logistic for binary? That is the angle I'm asking this question from.

Then you might consider changing the title and question.

"a simple linear model is not appropriate since it won't limit the predictions to 1-5":  that is true in theory but in practice the regression predictions may well stay within the 1-5 range or some narrower range.

@LearningScholar Discrete seems acceptable in theory, but with 33 levels you would have just as many marginal effects. This makes the ordered model hard to interpret in my eyes.

@LearningScholar Forget what I wrote; as I only notice now, your data aren't Likert scores but averages of Likert scores, so any ordered discrete variable model wouldn't make sense.

It appears from your comments (but not the text in your question) that your question is about the values the response can take rather than the frequencies of those values.  That is why I say your current question is unclear.

@JimB. Both. 1) The values of the response (their boundedness between 1-5 as well as their discreteness vs continuity) and 2) their frequencies (left-tailed distribution) both make me wonder if the response needs any transformation (not necessarily to normalize it) or any specific type of model may be needed in the same vein a negative binomial is needed when count response is overdispersed. As an illustrative example, I wonder if I may benefit from categorizing the response to get categories of nearly equal sizes [<4.2, 4.2-4.5, >4] and then fit a logistic regression.

Your data is not big, so you can always first choose a traditional linear regression at least as a baseline, if you're worried about the predicted output range you can employ the calibration technique of conformal prediction. If performance is not good due to interaction or other nonlinear effects, you can try more advanced random forests, boosts, MLP or (kernel) Gaussian processes.

I am going to propose an alternative to the ordered probit/logit approach that I have not seen used before. If this turns out to be a stupid idea, someone will surely point that out and we will all learn something.
The main idea is to divide the star rating by the max value of five, so that it lies in [0,1]. This leaves zero stars at zero and maps a perfect five-star business to one. This means you can use a fractional probit or logit on the rescaled outcome, get predictions and marginal effects, and then scale them back up to the familiar five-star scale. This model is computationally less demanding and suitable if you care merely about the change in the average rating.
Here's a toy example in Stata on some business ratings from Yelp. The distribution of ratings looks like this:

I will model the star rating as a function of a quadratic polynomial in latitude. I will consider the change in the average rating associated with moving 25 degrees further north. The effect from the fractional probit model is almost 1/3 of a star, and tightly estimated:
. clear

. // (1) Get Yelp Ratings Data
. copy "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/katazmic/yelpAnalytics/90534078aa062267a254d6c52285b54d97109385/yelp_academic_dataset_business.csv" yelp_businesses_raw.csv, replace

. // (2) Clean Up Variable Names To Be Palatable to Stata
. ! head -n 1 yelp_businesses_raw.csv | sed 's/\./_/g' | sed 's/ /_/g' | sed 's/,/ /g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' > varnames.csv


. import delimited varnames using "varnames.csv", clear case(lower) varnames(nonames)
(encoding automatically selected: ISO-8859-1)
(1 var, 1 obs)

. local oldvarnames = varnames[1]

. local oldvarnames = subinstr("`oldvarnames'", "attributes_good_for_kids", "attributes_good_for_kids1",1)

. local oldvarnames = subinstr("`oldvarnames'", "attributes_good_for_kids", "attributes_good_for_kids2",1)

. local oldvarnames = subinstr("`oldvarnames'", "attributes_", "attr_",.)

. local oldvarnames = subinstr("`oldvarnames'", "attr_dietary_restrictions_", "attr_diet_",.)

. local oldvarnames = subinstr("`oldvarnames'", "attr_hair_types_specialized_in_", "attr_hair_spec_in_",.)

. local newvarnames ""

. foreach var of local oldvarnames {
  2.     local newvarnames `"`newvarnames' `=lower(strtoname("`var'"))'"'
  3. }

. // (4) Import the Data and Rename With Clean Variables Names
. import delimited using yelp_businesses_raw.csv, clear delim(",") rowrange(2) varnames(nonames) bindquote(strict) case(lower)
(encoding automatically selected: ISO-8859-1)
(105 vars, 61,184 obs)

. rename (v*) (`newvarnames')

. // (5) Fractional Probit Model with Star Rating Rescaled to Lie in [0,1]
. gen stars_norm = stars/5

. assert inrange(stars_norm, 0, 1)

. fracreg probit stars_norm c.latitude##c.latitude, vce(robust) nolog


Fractional probit regression                            Number of obs = 61,184
                                                        Wald chi2(2)  = 122.72
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood = -35392.619                       Pseudo R2     = 0.0002

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      |               Robust
           stars_norm | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             latitude |  -.0273943   .0044782    -6.12   0.000    -.0361714   -.0186172
                      |
c.latitude#c.latitude |   .0003479   .0000513     6.79   0.000     .0002474    .0004484
                      |
                _cons |   1.153459    .094506    12.21   0.000     .9682306    1.338687
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // predict rescaled star rating at current latitude and at 25 degrees further north
. margins, at((asobserved) latitude) at(latitude = generate(latitude + 25)) post // coefl

Predictive margins                                      Number of obs = 61,184
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Conditional mean of stars_norm, predict()
1._at: (asobserved)                
2._at: latitude = latitude + 25

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         _at |
          1  |   .7346609   .0007201  1020.17   0.000     .7332495    .7360724
          2  |   .7891537    .004838   163.11   0.000     .7796714    .7986361
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // Calculate Finite Difference and Transform Back to Original Scale
. lincom 5*(_b[2._at] - _b[1._at]) // Effect is ~1/3 stars

 ( 1)  - 5*1bn._at + 5*2._at = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |    .272464    .024192    11.26   0.000     .2250484    .3198795
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For comparison, here's what the ordered probit model would look like (with fewer categories):
. // (6) Ordered Probit Model with Star Rating Categories
. recode stars (1 = "1") (1.5 = 2 "1.5") (2 = 3 "2") (2.5 = 4 "2.5") (3 = 5 "3") (3.5 = 6 "3.5") (4 = 7 "4") (4.5 = 8 "4.5") (5 = 9 "5"), gen(star_cat)
(60,547 differences between stars and star_cat)

. oprobit star_cat c.latitude##c.latitude, nolog

Ordered probit regression                               Number of obs = 61,184
                                                        LR chi2(2)    =  52.78
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log likelihood = -118357.1                              Pseudo R2     = 0.0002

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             star_cat | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             latitude |  -.0571126   .0091394    -6.25   0.000    -.0750256   -.0391996
                      |
c.latitude#c.latitude |   .0006907   .0001059     6.52   0.000     .0004831    .0008983
----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                /cut1 |  -3.459527    .191486                     -3.834833   -3.084221
                /cut2 |  -3.054382   .1912211                     -3.429169   -2.679596
                /cut3 |  -2.646753   .1911211                     -3.021343   -2.272162
                /cut4 |  -2.174837   .1910784                     -2.549344    -1.80033
                /cut5 |   -1.70519   .1910467                     -2.079635   -1.330745
                /cut6 |   -1.13739   .1910135                     -1.511769   -.7630103
                /cut7 |  -.5518906   .1909904                     -.9262248   -.1775564
                /cut8 |    .027655   .1909572                     -.3466143    .4019243
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // Get Pr(Category = j | Latitude)
. margins, at(latitude = generate(latitude)) at(latitude = generate(latitude + 25)) 

Adjusted predictions                                    Number of obs = 61,184
Model VCE: OIM

1._predict: Pr(star_cat==1), predict(pr outcome(1))
2._predict: Pr(star_cat==2), predict(pr outcome(2))
3._predict: Pr(star_cat==3), predict(pr outcome(3))
4._predict: Pr(star_cat==4), predict(pr outcome(4))
5._predict: Pr(star_cat==5), predict(pr outcome(5))
6._predict: Pr(star_cat==6), predict(pr outcome(6))
7._predict: Pr(star_cat==7), predict(pr outcome(7))
8._predict: Pr(star_cat==8), predict(pr outcome(8))
9._predict: Pr(star_cat==9), predict(pr outcome(9))

1._at: latitude =      latitude
2._at: latitude = latitude + 25

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
_predict#_at |
        1 1  |   .0103948   .0004099    25.36   0.000     .0095914    .0111983
        1 2  |   .0051554   .0005129    10.05   0.000     .0041502    .0061606
        2 1  |   .0178784   .0005355    33.38   0.000     .0168288     .018928
        2 2  |   .0100725   .0008187    12.30   0.000     .0084678    .0116772
        3 1  |   .0386198   .0007789    49.59   0.000     .0370933    .0401464
        3 2  |   .0238898   .0016102    14.84   0.000     .0207339    .0270458
        4 1  |   .0851714   .0011285    75.47   0.000     .0829595    .0873833
        4 2  |     .05853   .0031334    18.68   0.000     .0523887    .0646713
        5 1  |   .1362984   .0013876    98.23   0.000     .1335788    .1390179
        5 2  |   .1049775   .0041789    25.12   0.000     .0967871    .1131679
        6 1  |   .2153778   .0016624   129.56   0.000     .2121195     .218636
        6 2  |   .1893193   .0045789    41.35   0.000     .1803449    .1982938
        7 1  |   .2202074   .0016752   131.45   0.000      .216924    .2234907
        7 2  |   .2256132   .0020153   111.95   0.000     .2216632    .2295632
        8 1  |   .1558315   .0014666   106.26   0.000      .152957    .1587059
        8 2  |   .1886484   .0036141    52.20   0.000      .181565    .1957318
        9 1  |   .1202205   .0013143    91.47   0.000     .1176446    .1227965
        9 2  |   .1937938   .0120642    16.06   0.000     .1701484    .2174392
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // Calculate Finite Differences For Each Star Rating Category
. margins, at(latitude = generate(latitude)) at(latitude = generate(latitude + 25)) contrast(atcontrast(ar._at)) post

Contrasts of adjusted predictions                       Number of obs = 61,184
Model VCE: OIM

1._predict: Pr(star_cat==1), predict(pr outcome(1))
2._predict: Pr(star_cat==2), predict(pr outcome(2))
3._predict: Pr(star_cat==3), predict(pr outcome(3))
4._predict: Pr(star_cat==4), predict(pr outcome(4))
5._predict: Pr(star_cat==5), predict(pr outcome(5))
6._predict: Pr(star_cat==6), predict(pr outcome(6))
7._predict: Pr(star_cat==7), predict(pr outcome(7))
8._predict: Pr(star_cat==8), predict(pr outcome(8))
9._predict: Pr(star_cat==9), predict(pr outcome(9))

1._at: latitude =      latitude
2._at: latitude = latitude + 25

------------------------------------------------
             |         df        chi2     P>chi2
-------------+----------------------------------
_at@_predict |
 (2 vs 1) 1  |          1      109.03     0.0000
 (2 vs 1) 2  |          1       98.02     0.0000
 (2 vs 1) 3  |          1       89.54     0.0000
 (2 vs 1) 4  |          1       76.41     0.0000
 (2 vs 1) 5  |          1       59.89     0.0000
 (2 vs 1) 6  |          1       36.12     0.0000
 (2 vs 1) 7  |          1       24.35     0.0000
 (2 vs 1) 8  |          1      103.12     0.0000
 (2 vs 1) 9  |          1       38.05     0.0000
      Joint  |          8      766.12     0.0000
------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |   Contrast   std. err.     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
_at@_predict |
 (2 vs 1) 1  |  -.0052394   .0005018     -.0062229    -.004256
 (2 vs 1) 2  |  -.0078058   .0007884     -.0093511   -.0062606
 (2 vs 1) 3  |    -.01473   .0015567     -.0177811    -.011679
 (2 vs 1) 4  |  -.0266414   .0030477     -.0326148    -.020668
 (2 vs 1) 5  |  -.0313209   .0040472     -.0392532   -.0233885
 (2 vs 1) 6  |  -.0260584    .004336     -.0345568   -.0175601
 (2 vs 1) 7  |   .0054058   .0010954      .0032588    .0075528
 (2 vs 1) 8  |    .032817   .0032316       .026483    .0391509
 (2 vs 1) 9  |   .0735733   .0119267      .0501974    .0969491
--------------------------------------------------------------

. marginsplot, yline(0) xlab(1 "1" 2 "1.5" 3 "2" 4 "2.5" 5 "3" 6 "3.5" 7 "4" 8 "4.5" 9 "5") ylab(#10) ///
> title("Effect of Relocating 25 Degrees North on Each Star Ratings") ytitle("Change in Probability")

Variables that uniquely identify margins: _outcome
Multiple at() options specified:
      _atoption=1: latitude = generate(latitude)
      _atoption=2: latitude = generate(latitude + 25)


This shows that ratings in the left part of the star distribution become less probable, especially in the middle, while top ratings become more likely.
This took a bit longer to run since there are multiple effects, but it offers a richer picture of what's happening in all parts of the distribution.

@LearningScholar Thoughts on this approach?
